# Uniform convergence of all derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence and $f$ a function which are holomorphic on the open unit disk $D(0,1)$ and continuous on  $\overline{D(0,1)}$. 
Let also $f_n^{(k)}$ and $f^{(k)}$ be continuous on  $\overline{D(0,1)}$ $\quad \forall k \in \mathbf{N}$ . 
We suppose that $f_n= (1-z)g_n$ and $f=(1-z)g$ where $g_n,g$ and $g_n^{(k)}, g^{(k)}$ are continuous on $\overline{D(0,1)}$ $\quad \forall k \in \mathbf{N}$ .

If $f_n^{(k)} \rightarrow f^{(k)} $ uniformly on  $\overline{D(0,1)}$ $\quad \forall k=0,1,2,...    $  is it true that $g_n^{(k)} \rightarrow g^{(k)} $ uniformly on  $\overline{D(0,1)}$ $\quad \forall k=0,1,2,...  $ ?

Comment: Hint: if $|z| \leq 1$ has real part exceeding $0.5$, then $g_n(z)=\int_0^1{f_n’((1-z)u)du}$.

Comment: @Mindlack are you sure this equation holds? I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but I get different result calculating the integral.

Comment: Um, no. I think that should be $\int_0^1{f_n’(1-u+zu)du}$ instead.

Comment: (The “no” applied to the “are you sure that...” – the previous formula is wrong and the above comment should repair it).

Comment: @Mindlack yes, I've found out the correct formula. Thanks a lot!